# Accessing global file in the user defined function

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, file

I am trying to access file which is opened globally as below:

```
with open("number.txt") as num:
    val=int(num.read())
```

consider `number.txt` will be having some number
After the above lines of code if I use the above file pointer inside a method as below:

```
def updateval():
    global num
    num.write(numb)
```

I am getting error as :`ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`
If I open file inside function then there wont be any issue.But I want to open file only once so in many opther function I can perform file operation without opening again and again

Please help me in resolving this!!
Many thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. `with` closes the file when the enclosing code block exists.
2. You open the file for reading, so even if you don't close the file, you can't write to it.

Solution 1:

```
with open('number.txt') as num:  # opens for read-only by default
    val = int(num.read())
# file is closed here

def updateval(numb):
    with output('number.txt','w') as num:  # re-opened for writing
        num.write(numb)
    # file is closed here
```

Solution 2 (if you really want to open the file once):

```
num = open('number.txt','r+')  # Open for reading and updating.
val = int(num.read())

def updateval(numb):
    # You don't need "global" when you mutate an object,
    # only for new assignment, e.g. num = open(...)
    num.seek(0)           # make sure to write at the beginning of the file.
    num.truncate()        # erase the current content.
    num.write(str(numb))  # write the number as a string
    num.flush()           # make sure to flush it to disk.
```

Obviously, the second solution you have to micromanage what you are doing.  Use solution 1.

Comment: I was trying for the solution 2 ... Thanks alot. All I messed up in mentioning `file operation mode` as well as converting val to `string` before writing!!
Your meaningful comments along side of code really helpful for beginners like me...

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of a `with` statement is that the `file` is closed when you leave that scope. The advantage of this is that if you get `errors`, the file is closed properly.

So when you do the following:

```
with open("number.txt") as num:
    val=int(num.read())
```

you assign the contents of `number.txt` to `val` and **then close the `file`**.

So therefore, when you try and `write` to it later (no matter if you are in a `function` or not), you will get the `error` that you posted in the question:

```
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

---

So if you really want to be able to `write` to the `file` inside any `function` without having to keep opening it, you just have to **not** use a `with` statement, just `open` the file for `writing` (`'w'`) explicitly and `close` it at the end of the program.

So the main outline of your code would look something like:

```
with open("number.txt") as num:
    val=int(num.read())

file = open("number.txt", "w")

def writeToFile(data):
    global file
    #more code
    file.write(data)
    #more code

#more code

file.close()
```

*note this is **not** good practice, you should pass the `file` object into the `function` and remove the use of `global` variables*